# Way to make a swipe left and right style image browser / gallery in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, slideshow

I am designing my wordpress based portfolio and I found this website: [utopiasupps.com/product/preworkout](https://utopiasupps.com/product/preworkout)

I really love their tinder-style image browser that can be used for some kind of image gallery, how it tilts as you swipe and feels pretty responsive, is there an easy way to recreate this on wordpress or a plugin that can be used?

I've tried depictor but it didn't give the effect needed, and after browsing through the plugins available I couldn't really find anything that offered this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this seems like it might do what you need: https://medium.com/@simonepm/build-a-full-featured-tinder-like-carousel-in-vanilla-javascript-part-i-44ca3a906450